# Counting the number of methods defined in a C++ header

Tags: c++

Is there a tool to count the number of methods defined in a header? This seems like something that people would want to do from time to time, but I've never heard of such a utility. I could roll my own (and it'd be quite easy to come up with something that works for me in *this* particular case), but I thought I'd try stackoverflow first :)

Thanks,
Yi

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
ctags --c++-kinds=f -x myfile.h
```

To list all functions in the file myfile.h . To count the number of functions in `deque.tcc`:

```
$ ctags --c++-kinds=f --language-force=c++ -x deque.tcc | wc -l
24
```

Comment: +1, but the ctags I have on my MacBook doesn't support C++; only C, Pascal, Fortran, YACC, lex, and lisp.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield,
Firstly, `brew install ctags`

And then `alias ctags="`brew --prefix`/bin/ctags"`

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if doxygen --> http://www.doxygen.nl/ does it, but I wouldn't be surprised if it also does that.

It generates documentation from the header files + javadoc like comments.

It will find the functions also so that kinda is counting.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the Visual Studio plugin. In which you can access each class, and each methods in it. This uses COM technology and Visual studio extensibility feature.

EDIT: I have never seen the tag cocoa in question. This answer applies only to Visual studio